Spark-Scala vs Pyspark Dag is different?
I am converting pyspark job to Scala and jobs executes in emr. The parameter and data and code is same. However I see the run time is different and so also the dag getting created is different. Here I am adding the data read part from UI. If you see the number of outputrows task in the UI.
**Spark-submit command**
spark-submit --conf spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes=268435456 \
--master yarn --deploy-mode cluster  --conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1 \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.enabled=true --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false \
--conf spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown=true \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled=true \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.advisoryPartitionSizeInBytes=268435456 \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.optimizeSkewsInRebalancePartitions.enabled=true \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.rebalancePartitionsSmallPartitionFactor=.5 \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.parallelismFirst=false \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.initialPartitionNum=12000 \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.localShuffleReader.enabled=true \
--conf spark.shuffle.io.connectionTimeout=8000 \
--conf spark.network.timeout=50000s  --conf spark.files.fetchTimeout=600s \
--conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer --conf spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=1g \
--conf spark.memory.storageFraction=0.05 --conf spark.memory.fraction=.8 \
--conf spark.shuffle.compress=true --conf spark.shuffle.spill.compress=true \
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3.multipart.th.fraction.parts.completed=0.99 \
--conf spark.sql.objectHashAggregate.sortBased.fallbackThreshold=4000000 \
--conf spark.reducer.maxReqsInFlight=12 \
--conf spark.shuffle.io.retryWait=60s \
--conf spark.shuffle.io.maxRetries=10 \
--conf spark.reducer.maxSizeInFlight=256m \
--conf spark.reducer.maxBlocksInFlightPerAddress=100 \
--conf spark.io.compression.codec=zstd \
--conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true \
--conf spark.io.compression.zstd.level=3 \
--conf spark.executor.cores=5 \
--conf spark.executor.instances=1200 \
--conf spark.executor.memory=34g --conf spark.driver.memory=60g --conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=5g --conf spark.driver.memoryOverhead=4g \
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.output.enabled=true \
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+G1SummarizeConcMark -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p' -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/home/hadoop/.config/certs/InternalAndExternalTrustStore.jks" --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-XX:+UseG1GC " \
test.py

First Dag is from pyspark execution and 2nd one is Scala.



Pls show code for all.

This answer, albeit a slightly different question, explains what ColumnarToRow is probably doing in your python plans, but in short it's the translation layer to the jvm representation of InternalRows used within Spark's execution.
In the typical use cases using Scala you'd not see it.
edit: this SO provides some code examples in addition to the basic question
